# Can two Rails threads be using the same Postgres session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, postgresql-9.6

My Rails app is getting duplicate key errors from insertions in a Postgres table (one of the columns has a uniqueness constraint). I used a Postgres session-level [advisory lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) as a mutex but it's still happening.

My theory is that two Rails workers are sharing the same Postgres session, and so the second one doesn't get blocked by the first. Is that even possible?